# Why is string number addition not coalescing intuitively

Tags: javascript

Why is the last operation returning 20?

```js
console.log(2 + 2); // equals 4
console.log("2" + "2"); // equals "22"
console.log(2 + 2 - 2); // equals 2
console.log("2" + "2" - "2"); // equals 20
```

Comment: Infact doing ```"2"+"2"-"2"+"2"``` returns "202" this is intresting

Comment: Because 22 - 2. Note that strings do not have a `-` operator so the `"22"` is coerced into a number `22`

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: @NishantShamVispute `"2"+"2"-"2"+"2"` -> `"22" - "2" + "2"` -> `20 + "2"` -> `"202"`

Comment: @VLAZ there must be a couple of questions with chaining them together somewhere.

Comment: @adiga probably. Can't think of one off the top of my head but it might be under the type coercion rather than just `+` and `-`. I'll try to have a look when I have the time.

Comment: @adiga yeah i now get the concepts of **concatenation** & **coerce**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`+` and `-` evaluate left-to-right. When either operand is a string, the result is concatenation. When both are numbers, the result is addition.

In contrast, `-` will always coerce both sides to numbers.

```
'2' + '2' - '2'
```

does

```
// left-to-right
('2' + '2') - '2'
// both sides are strings, so concatenate
'22' - '2'
// operator is -, so coerce both sides to numbers
22 - 2
20
```

Answer (score 1):

The signs `+` and `-` work very differently in string concatenation. The `+` operator gives direct concatenation instructions on strings whereas the `-` operator tries to coerce the types and perform the mathematical function.

```js
console.log("2" + "2");
console.log(typeof ("2" + "2"));

console.log("2" - "2");
console.log(typeof("2" - "2"));
```

Comment: "*The + operator gives direct concatenation instructions on strings whereas the - operator tries to coerce the types and perform the mathematical function.*" The `+` operator will also do coercion when mixed type operands are used. Which is what happens with `s1 - s2 + s3` if all three are strings containing valid numerics. `s1 - s2` would produce a number, and `+ s3` would coerce back to string.

Comment: `+` operator will try to perform the concatenation by coercing if non-string values are given.

Comment: Yes, as I said: "*when mixed type operands are used.*"

Comment: Yes. That is one way to put it.